# Finding text with a batch file using Notepad++

Tags: text, batch-file, find, notepad++

I need to find text in a file when I open it with Notepad++.
For instance I need to find the text "ABC".  However the true text I need are 2 numbers that follow "ABC".  So I have a batch file that uses Notepad++ to open a particular file when I double click it.  It needs to find ABC and then look at the 2 digits directly following it and populate a variable with them.

Some files might contain ABC12 while others might contain ABC21, etc.

All I have so far is the following:

```
%echo off
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" %1 
FIND [/I] "ABC"
```

It opens the file fine, but does not search.  Please help!
Thanks!

Comment: Your `FIND` command will not operate with the content of Notepad++. They will run in different environments.  You will need to use NotePad's own scripting, which seems to be possible with [`Python` plug-in](http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I made some edits on the script.

Answer (score 7):

this is a really nice question! Try this:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
set "LineNr="
for /f "tokens=1*delims=[]" %%a in ('^<"%~1" find /i /n "%~2"') do if not defined LineNr (
    set "LineNr=%%a"
    SET "Line=%%b"
)
if not defined LineNr (
    set "LineNr=1"
    SET "Row=1"
    GOTO :launch
)
CALL SET "Right=%~2%%Line:*%~2=%%"
CALL SET "Line=%%Line:%Right%=%%"
FOR /f "delims=:" %%a in ('"(echo("%Line%"&@echo()|findstr /o $"') do SET /a Row=%%a-4
:launch
START /b CMD /c ""%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" -n%LineNr% -c%Row% "%~1""
```

calling the batch:

```
script.bat "D:\PATH\FILE.TXT" "STRING TO SEARCH"
```

[notepad++ command line switches](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Command_Line_Switches)